# .NET Core 3.1 deps.json use dll from another folder

Tags: .net-core

How can I tell my Console application to use dll in subfolder?
My application will be dropped in parent folder with other application with theirs own libraries.
dll1 is used by parent application and have version 4 and exists in parent folder.
I need to use dll1 with version 6 which i am planning to put in subfolder.